# Passing a string to clickHandler in a react functional component

Tags: reactjs

I tried without success to pass a string in a functionnal component clickHandler. In this code, is there a easy way to pass a string (to replace the "/about") so i can use this functional components anywhere?

```html
function NavigationButton () {
    //const [setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
    const [show, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
    const history = useHistory();
    function handleClick() {
        setAnchorEl(null);
        history.push("/about");
    }
    return <MenuItem onClick={handleClick}>About</MenuItem>;
}
```

I want to be able to do this

```
<Menu id="simple-menu"
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  keepMounted
  open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
  onClose={handleClose}>
  <NavigationButton path="/about" />
  <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Users</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>About</MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your functional component to take the passed `path` prop.

```
const NavigationButton = ({ path = '/' }) => { // define the accepted prop, with default
  const [show, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleClick = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    history.push(path);
  }

  return <MenuItem onClick={handleClick}>About</MenuItem>;
}
```

or

```
function NavigationButton ({ path = '/' }) { // define the accepted prop, with default
  const [show, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleClick = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    history.push(path);
  }

  return <MenuItem onClick={handleClick}>About</MenuItem>;
}
```

Passing the `onClick` callback

```
const NavigationButton = ({ onClick, path = '/' }) => { // define the accepted prop, with default
  const [show, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    onClick && onClick(event); // pass out event object incase parent cares
    history.push(path);
  }

  return <MenuItem onClick={handleClick}>About</MenuItem>;
}
```

So this will now work

```
<Menu id="simple-menu"
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  keepMounted
  open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
  onClose={handleClose}
>
  <NavigationButton onClick={handleClose} path="/about" /> // passing the `onClick` AND `path` props
  <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Users</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>About</MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: But why NavigationButton has to become a const? sorry i am rather new to react and i see way too many ways to make things up. It is similar to how i defined it?

Comment: Oh, it doesn't, it's just a preference of mine with functional components. I'll update to show both.

Comment: Ok so function NameOfFunction ({ path = '/' }) { ... is equivalent to const NameOfFunction = ({ path = '/' }) => { ... ?

Comment: They are nearly equivalent. In most cases they can be used interchangeably, but there are subtle differences and gotchas. [difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions](https://medium.com/better-programming/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256)

Comment: THanks for your help. There one thing that doesn't work through. The menu won't close for theses buttons.. but do for MenuItem and i wonder why. I though Hooks that use the state would share the state.

Comment: Each functional component using hooks is using its own copy of the hook. If you also want `NavigationButton` to close then pass the `onClick` prop to it as well. Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Passing the setting anchor function seem to also work. const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] and then i set it to null.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this ?

```
<MenuItem onClick={()=>handleClick("Your String")}>About</MenuItem>
 function handleClick(yourString) {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    history.push("/"+yourString);
}
```